# How to write push notification using .net webservice in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. I need to write a .net webservice to send notification (push notification) to my application. I already worked using php webservice to send push notification but is it possible to write a .net webservice? If its possible please suggest me some links.

Will be really thankful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many samples and tutorials. Did a search in Google and found [this](http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/05/push-messages-to-gcm-server-using-net.html)

Comment: thank you so much i will try that example and get back to you.

Comment: Is this really an answer!?